# Python Nested tuples to list

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql query that runs and selects all of the Id's that match the select statement:

```
first_seen_select = "SELECT Id FROM domains_archive WHERE current_epoch = " + current_epoch + " AND first_seen IS NULL"
cur.execute(first_seen_select)
```

The output of `cur.fetchall()` is

```
((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,))
```

**How do i extract these nested tuple Id #'s and convert them into a single list that i can iterate over?**

If i run the following i get:

```
>>> bleh = cur.fetchall()
>>> for i in bleh:
...   print(i)
... 
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)
(6,)
(7,)
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't know where `current_epoch` comes from, but best practice is not to format your query like that and to instead pass it as a format param to `cur.execute` to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @mgilson thanks, i am aware this is open to sql injection right now, i will parameterize this once i get the logic all worked out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a simple list comprehension:

```
[y for x in l for y in x]
```

Or with more meaningful variable names:

```
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

this will result in:

```
In [8]: l = ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,))

In [9]: [y for x in l for y in x]
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: List comprehensions still make my head hurt. haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a fun (although not clear/unpractical) way to flatten it using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
In [1]: bleh = ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,))

In [2]: sum(bleh, ())
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

It works like that - iterates over the outer tuple and sums all the values inside:

```
In [3]: (1,) + (2,) + (3,) + (4,) + (5,) + (6,) + (7,)
Out[3]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

And, as you see, if you add a tuple to a tuple, you get another tuple with all the values of those tuples.

By passing an empty tuple - `()` - as a second argument to the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function, we basically tell it to use it as an initial argument to start adding from, so it would actually work like that:

```
In [4]: () + (1,) + (2,) + (3,) + (4,) + (5,) + (6,) + (7,)
Out[4]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: What are these' In [2]: , Out[2]: that i am seeing?

Comment: Output from the ipython console

Comment: @dobbs It's [IPython](http://ipython.org/)'s prompt, feel free to ignore it :) It's like when you just run `python` and see `>>> ` there.

Comment: As a Python beginner, this is such an unusual language. Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
result = [x[0] for x in cur.fetchall()]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lt = ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,))

from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(lt))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

A general way to create a list from a nested tuple would be:

```
def tupleToList(nestedTuple):
    def gen(tuple_):
        for item in tuple_:
            if type(item) is tuple:
                yield from gen(item)
            else:
                yield item
    return [value for value in gen(nestedTuple)]
```

Note that everything is flattened. Example usage:

```
>>> print(tupleToList((('a','b'), ('c', 'd', ('e')))))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```